# Indexing an output result

Tags: python, list

I have two list: `abbi= [a,b,c,d,e]` and `james=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`. I then did `x=[i for i in james if i not in abbi]` to print out `[f,g,h]`. But I also want to print out the index of the result. So in this case, it would be `[5,6,7]`. I am new to programming and not sure how this can be done. I tried doing something with `.idex` command, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: ```x=[[y,james.index(y)] for y in james if y not in abbi]```??

Comment: You need to maintain the index, so it either needs to be list of tuple, list of list, or dictionary, a 2D sequence.

Comment: @Sujay, that gave me the following error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Interesting, it works on my machine

Comment: @Sujay, actually it worked now, but it returns `[[f, 5], [g, 6], [h, 7]]`. What I wanted was just the indices, so `[5,6,7]`.

Comment: There's no need to call `index`, which is inefficient and won't work if there are duplicates.  Just use `[i for i, v in enumerate(james) if v not in abbi]`.  And if `abbi` is long, convert it to a `set` first for improved speed.

Comment: ```x=[y for y,x in enumerate(james) if y not in abbi]```

Comment: @Zegary Just remember, if `abbi` is long, you can convert it to a set for a fast membership test.  That will avoid O(n**2) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code sample will satisfy your use case -

```
abbi= ['a','b','c','d','e']
james=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
x=[]
y=[]
for i in range(0,len(james)):
    if james[i] not in abbi:
        x.append(james[i])
        y.append(i)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Yes @TomKarzes. You are correct. Thanks for reminding me. I will update my answer.